# Get Containers with Masonry Object

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-masonry, masonry

Ex: There are three  containers 'A','B' and 'C'. Containers 'A' and 'B' are masonry objects. I want to know what all containers are masonry binded. So looking for a function which will return me 'A' and 'B'. Any Idea how to achieve this? Searched their documentation but didn't find a solution http://masonry.desandro.com/methods.html

Reason: I want to create a function globally which reloads all my masonry objects present on the page on ajax or data addition. Since each page will have different masonry containers, I first need to find containers and reload them manually

Answer (score 1):

As you can see in your code, masonry use specific classes to set up himself. 
For example: 
http://desandro.github.io/masonry/ >> here you have class "masonry-brick" used on each container which contain floating elements.

Why not to use this class? 
U can create global foo, like:
`window.findMasonry= function(){
  $('body').find('.masonry-brick').each(function(){
     //do something})
  }`

You can easily find element parents so ways are open :).

But if you want to check specifically binded event name, you can use data('events'). Works only for jQuery binded events.

Comment: Thanks for your guidance but event if parent container is available to me,  how will i get masonry object name? Any thoughts on that

Comment: I think i dont understand what you need :). 
There is one class which is added to container by masonry. 
You can count elements with this class easly, check their parent and so on.